# Trouble getting WCF to work with netTcpBinding

Tags: .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

Below is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Indexer">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/Indexer/" binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="TransactionalTCP" contract="Me.IIndexer" />
      </service>
      <service name = "Indexer" behaviorConfiguration = "MEXGET">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name = "MEXGET">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled = "true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TransactionalTCP"
           transactionFlow="true"
         />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

For some reason, I cannot get to the WCF service on the machine where I run this.
Can any one spot the error? I have netTcpBinding service up and running.

When I had the same running in HTTP it was working fine with the following .config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="IndexerServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8080/Indexer/"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Indexer" behaviorConfiguration="IndexerServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Indexer/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="" name="HTTP" contract="IIndexer" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Indexer/MEX/" binding="mexHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="" name="MEX" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, of course, opened up the firewall to let it listen?

If it's any use, here's the binding I successfully used not so long ago:

```
<services>

  <service name="MyService.MySearch" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://mypc:8003/MyService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="MyService.IMySearch"
              address="net.tcp://mypc:8004/MyService"  />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             portSharingEnabled="false">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

There's no security on this binding.

Comment: I only said it because it cost me about twenty minutes the other day :)

Comment: Ahh you have no mex endpoint, when you go to add service refernce in visual studio, can you just give it the net.tcp address?

Comment: no. notice that it has an http base address which seemed to work nicely. never bothered getting my head round the mex stuff. didn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to [Enable the Net.TCP Port Sharing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733925.aspx). Quote from MSDN:

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   uses a Windows service called the
>   Net.TCP Port Sharing Service to
>   facilitate the sharing of TCP ports
>   across multiple processes. This
>   service is installed as part of WCF,
>   but the service is not enabled by
>   default as a security precaution and
>   so must be manually enabled prior to
>   first use. This topic describes how to
>   configure the Net TCP Port Sharing
>   Service using the Microsoft Management
>   Console (MMC) snap-In.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different port numbers for http and net.tcp binding. Port sharing has a different purpose, to share the same net.tcp port among multiple processes.